# WPF: prevent user from leaving TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, event-handling, focus

I won other battles and lost this one -- wherein our design sometimes forces users to fields. Obviously the code samples are oversimplified. Let me know if I need to provide more details somewhere.

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="5,5,0,0" Name="textBox1" />
        <TextBox Height="23" Margin="5,65,0,0" Name="textBox2" />
        <ComboBox Height="23" Margin="5,125,0,0" Name="comboBox1" >
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Lorem Ipsum" />
        </ComboBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**XAML.CS:**

```
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace WpfApplication1 {
    public partial class MainWindow {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox1.Focus();
            textBox1.PreviewLostKeyboardFocus += Foo;
        }

        void Foo(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e) {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

The app launches w/ the focus/cursor on textBox1 by default.  The PreviewLostKeyboardFocus handler of that TextBox prevents the user from moving focus to textBox2 w/ either the keyboard *or* the mouse.

But the user *is* able, with the mouse, to move the focus to comboBox1.

Why is the user able to move the focus to comboBox1 using the mouse, and how can I force the user to remain in textBox1?

Comment: The combo box never _gains_ focus, it's just clicked on which opens it.  That's a completely different kind of interaction.  You'll probably have to disable the combo box or otherwise, prevent it from receiving certain events.

Comment: this feels like a bad design. I do not like a UI control being present and not clickable/editable. Perhaps you should implement a wizard-like UI to force an order. This is just confusing.

Comment: You should disable controls if you don't want them to get focus.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        textBox1.Focus();
        textBox1.LostFocus += (s, e) => 
                   Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() => textBox1.Focus()));
    }
```

?

Answer (score 1):

Try:

comboBox1.IsHitTestVisible = false;

Comment: I didn't know about IsHitTestVisible.  Thank you.  I'm ideally looking for an enforcement that lives entirely on textBox1.

Comment: Gotcha.  I think the issue lies in the fact that clicking on the combobox doesnt change keyboard focus.  Another approach might be to put all the code to prevent this on the Window class instead (pulling it out of the textBox1 too).  I'll put that method as a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just handle it on the window level:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        textBox1.Focus();
        this.PreviewMouseDown += new MouseButtonEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown);
        this.PreviewKeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown);
    }

    void MainWindow_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Tab) e.Handled = true;
    }

    void MainWindow_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```